# Chop text file using VI

Tags: vi

How could I chop text file using VI?
The problem is that text file is used by running application that put logging there hence I can't delete the file but can write there.
So what is the shortest way (key bindings) to clean the text file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the entire contents of a newly opened file, you can use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to open the file in order to clear the content, just run `echo "" > /filepath` and if there is a need to open the file use SHIFT+v at the beginning of the file and then G to go to the end of the file and then x to clear and :wq to save